# Unable to delete files from specific blob container

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to delete all files in specific folder from blob container in the azure server in asp.net mvc. I am providing the relative path to the funtion but it is not working.

Path is like "UserDate/Certificates/1288/"

Main function:

```
public override int Delete(string path)
        {
            // if path is null then throw ArgumentNullException
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(path))
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("path");
            }

            // Changing path, i.e removing invalid characters and replacing slashes
            path = ChangePath(path);

            bool result = false;

            int lastIndexOfSlash = path.LastIndexOf(@"\", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
            int lastIndexOfDot = path.LastIndexOf(".", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
            int slashesCount = path.Count(w => w == '\\');

            // if path belongs to file then delete file
            if ((lastIndexOfSlash > -1) && (lastIndexOfDot > -1) && (lastIndexOfDot > lastIndexOfSlash))
            {
                // Splitting fullName and getting container name and blobname
                BlobFullName blobFullName = GetContainerAndBlobName(path);
                string containerName = blobFullName.ContainerName;
                string blobName = blobFullName.BlobName;

                // Deleting blob and getting status code
                result = DeleteBlob(containerName, blobName);
            }
            else if ((slashesCount == 0) || (slashesCount == 1 && lastIndexOfSlash == (path.Length - 1)))
            {
                // Deleting container and getting status code
                result = DeleteContainer(path);
            }
            else
            {
                // Deleting directory and getting status code
                result = DeleteDirectory(path);
            }

            // returning status code
            if (result == false)
                return 0;
            else
                return 1;
        }
```

Helper Functions:

```
private static BlobFullName GetContainerAndBlobName(string path)
        {
            // if path is null then throw ArgumentNullException object.
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(path))
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("path");
            }

            // Gets slash index and checks that slash exists in path
            int indexOfSlash = path.IndexOf('\\', 0);
            if (indexOfSlash < 0)
            {
                indexOfSlash = path.IndexOf('/', 0);
            }
            Check.Require(indexOfSlash > 0);

            // Reference for container name
            string containerName = path.Substring(0, indexOfSlash);

            // Reference for blob name
            string blobName = path.Substring(indexOfSlash + 1);

            // Ensure that container name and blobname are not null
            Check.Ensure(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(containerName));
            Check.Ensure(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(blobName));

            // changing case of container name and blob name to lower case and retruning them
            BlobFullName blob = new BlobFullName();
            blob.ContainerName = containerName.ToLower(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            blob.BlobName = blobName.ToLower(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

            return blob;
        }

private bool DeleteBlob(string containerName, string blobName)
        {
            //Checking that block block account and blob clients are not null
            Check.Require(BlockBlob.Account != null);
            Check.Require(BlockBlob.BlobClient != null);

            try
            {
                // Getting container reference from blob client
                CloudBlobContainer container = BlockBlob.BlobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);

                //Ensure that client is not null
                Check.Require(container != null);

                // Getting CloudBlockBlob reference based upon blobname and ensuring that it's not null
                CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);
                Check.Require(blob != null);

                // Deleting blob and returing success message [i.e true]
                return blob.DeleteIfExists();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

private bool DeleteContainer(string containerName)
        {
            //Checking that block block account and blob clients are not null
            Check.Require(BlockBlob.Account != null);
            Check.Require(BlockBlob.BlobClient != null);

            try
            {
                // Getting reference of CloudBlobContainer based upon container name and ensuring that object is not null
                CloudBlobContainer container = BlockBlob.BlobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
                Check.Require(container != null);

                //Deleting container and returning success message [i.e true]
                return container.DeleteIfExists();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        private bool DeleteDirectory(string directoryPath)
        {
            //Checking that block block account and blob clients are not null
            Check.Require(BlockBlob.Account != null);
            Check.Require(BlockBlob.BlobClient != null);
            Check.Require(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(directoryPath) == false);

            try
            {
                // Getting reference of CloudBlobContainer based upon container name and ensuring that object is not null
                CloudBlobContainer container = BlockBlob.BlobClient.GetContainerReference(directoryPath);
                Check.Require(container != null);

                List<CloudBlockBlob> blobs = new List<CloudBlockBlob>();
                ListBlobs(container.Name, out blobs);

                if (blobs != null)
                {
                    foreach (CloudBlockBlob blob in blobs)
                    {
                        string fullBlobName = container.Name + @"/" + blob.Name;

                        if (fullBlobName.StartsWith(directoryPath.Replace('\\', '/'), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                        {
                            DeleteBlob(container.Name, blob.Name);
                        }
                    }
                }

                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Mainly I want to delete all files in the provided path.
Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: In your `DeleteDirectory` why are you creating container reference with full directory path? Should't it be the 1st element of your path?

Comment: I want to delete just the ending directory in from path. Not the start directory.

Answer (score 1):

In your command `DeleteBlob(container.Name, blob.Name);` are you passing the full blob path and filename to the command along with the container, or just the blob file name?

Also, your `DeleteDirectory(path);` command will never work as there's no such thing as an empty directory in blob storage. The directory is deleted along with the last file in that directory.

Comment: In my code, I am passing full path like `UserDate\Certificates\1288\`` of blob container. And then I am deleting all blobs in this container.
Here: 
`CloudBlobContainer container = BlockBlob.BlobClient.GetContainerReference(directoryPath);`

Comment: are all of your containers, directories and files in the storage account definitely lower case? I noticed your helper converts the string to lower. Everything in blob storage is case sensitive so `delete file` will not delete `File`

Comment: Yes they are in lowercase.

Comment: The problem is only with directories inside container not with an individual container.

Comment: Just to take a step back, there's actually no such thing as a folder/directory in Azure blob storage. You have Containers and Blobs. The folders you see in the portal are programmed in the UI.

So let's say you have `userdate/dertificates/1288/file.exe` the actual blob name is `userdate/dertificates/1288/file.exe`, not `file.exe`. If you want to delete all blobs in a "directory" then you'll need to match the pattern `userdate/dertificates/1288/*`

Comment: Suppose I need to delete all blobs with a pattern `userdata/certificates/1288/` knowing `userdata` is a container. How I should be doing this?

Comment: Just use regex to grab it then trim from the path.  Regex `(^.*?)(?=\/)`

Comment: Also, does it have to be in C#?

Comment: Yes, it has to be in c#.